# How to add action menu on specific position

Tags: acumatica

As per title. A new action menu is automatically added to the bottom of the list. Is there a way to force them to appear on specific index or just before/after a specific action ?

[image]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In Automation Steps screen, in Actions tab you can find the button REORDER ACTIONS, this may help you.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

PXGraph class has an action collections declared as:

```
public readonly PXActionCollection Actions;
```

It is a class deriving from .Net framework OrderedDictionary.

You can access it directly in your class deriving from PXGraph:

```
this.Actions
```

In the context of a graph extension deriving from PXGraphExtension it is available though Base member:

```
Base.Actions
```

Look at the public methods exposed by Actions, I think Move might be able to swap the Actions order in the menu. Here is some usage examples:

```
public PXAction<APInvoice> release;
public PXAction<APInvoice> prebook;

// Resolving name with static check
Base.Actions.Move(nameof(release), nameof(prebook));

// Using action display name with runtime check
Base.Actions.Move("Release", "Pre-book");
```